# $5$ persons in auditorium.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways $5$ persons can enter into a auditorium having $4$ entries.

My work:

First I choose $4$ persons out of $5$, $\#=5$, then multiplying it by $4!$ should give all possible combinations, but $5\times 4!$ don't matches with the answers.

Please help.

Comment: There are unstated assumptions here.  What is a "way".  Is it allowed for all 5 to come through entrance number one, simultaneously (side by side) an allowed way? Or $5!$ allowed ways? We can reverse engineer the question if the given answer is $5! 4^5$, but given the question as posed, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 people and each of them has 4 choices. If the order in which they enter is not important (I am assuming by the wording of your question that it's not), then you have $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4$ different ways they can enter the auditorium, so the answer would be $4^5$.